# Angular web app variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on my first Angular app and I'm running into an issue I can't seem to figure out how to solve. The app is meant to output several calculations that depend on user input. The results are displayed in a chart where I'm changing height of stacked divs. All of this is working correctly except for years tabs functionality.There are only 3 tabs. 3,4,5 years. Default tab is 4 years. Calculations consider year selected and my code works perfectly if switching from 4 and 3 years and 4 and 5 years but not between 3 and 5.

To keep track of year selected I have function below. The problem with my function is that initial_cost variable should store cost of default year 4, but currently it stores the cost of last year selected(just like prev_cost) so switching between 3 and 5 doesn't work correctly. I need to be able to compare with cost of year 4 based on previously selected user input.

How can I properly store value of initial_cost to reflect cost of default year 4? Note cost depends on user input so if input changes cost of default year 4 should too.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
    /* Function calls  when year is changed */
    $scope.year_changes = function (x) {
        $scope.initial_cost = $scope.total.other.total_cost; //NOT WORKING
        $scope.year = x;
        $scope.prod_cost_other();
        $scope.prod_cost_steelfusion();
        $scope.opera_cost_steelfusion();
        $scope.opera_cost_other();
        $scope.total_cost_steelfusion();
        $scope.prev_cost = $scope.total.other.total_cost;
        $scope.total_cost_other();
        $scope.updated_cost = $scope.total.other.total_cost;
        $scope.total_saving();
        $scope.percent_saving();

        if ($scope.year == 4) { //4 years selected
            $scope.charts_ww_hght = $scope.charts_dflt_ww_hght; //default height
        } else if ($scope.year == 5) { //5 years selected
            if ($scope.prev_cost != $scope.updated_cost) { //only update if year is changed
                $scope.total_cost_change_percentage = 100 - (($scope.initial_cost * 100) / $scope.updated_cost);
                $scope.percent_difference_in_px = ($scope.total_cost_change_percentage * $scope.charts_dflt_ww_hght) / 100;
                $scope.charts_ww_hght = (190 + $scope.percent_difference_in_px);
            }
        } else if ($scope.year == 3) { //3 years selected
            if ($scope.prev_cost != $scope.updated_cost) { //only update if year is changed
                $scope.total_cost_change_percentage = 100 - (($scope.updated_cost * 100) / $scope.initial_cost);
                $scope.percent_difference_in_px = ($scope.total_cost_change_percentage * $scope.charts_dflt_ww_hght) / 100;
                $scope.charts_ww_hght = ($scope.charts_dflt_ww_hght - $scope.percent_difference_in_px);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do all of these variables really need to be in the $scope object?  Where is `$scope.total.other.total_cost` being set?

Comment: I don't know that there's really enough context here to answer the question.  One thing to consider is do not use the $scope as your model instead have it point at an object that is the model, this will help you avoid seemingly strange things happening due to prototypical inheritance of scopes.  Would suggest also doing all this work on the data in a factory and then just inject it into the controller and expose it on the scope, typically makes things easier to work on.  Also curious why not use some existing chart directive or write the parts that handle sizing into a directive?

Comment: @aaronmallen this is the funtion for $scope.total.other.total_cost: 
        $scope.total_cost_other = function () {
            $scope.total.other.total_cost = $scope.total.other.infra_cost + $scope.total.other.oper_cost + $scope.total.other.prod_cost;
            return $scope.total.other.total_cost;
        }

Comment: @shaunhusain Thanks for your reply! The entire app works and data displays correctly in the charts. Just this last one issue on year function. Is there anything else I could look into or can you further explain. Would It be possible to use a helper function or create a variable outside of year function to keep track of cost of default year 4 that I could update from year function.